# Git: get back my commited data from a messed up local repo

Tags: git

I am a newbie to git so I think I made something stupid

Assume I'm at version A and I commited a change but didn't want that. Now assume we have version B. I didn't found a good solution how to cleanly roll B back to A but went back to A via checkout and continued commiting - assume I have version C.

```
A--->B
 \-->C
```

Now the problem is that those commits were successfull (I can see the SHA's and the msg in .git/logs/HEAD)

but the commits do not show up in the log and I couldn't push them to github. Before detecting the mess I checkout to 'master' ... and git rolled all back to B.

**How can I get my version C back or are my changes lost?**

Is this the same problem as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/116153/rescuing-files-and-commits-from-no-branch-in-git)?

Comment: Does the commit that you are missing show up in the reflog? `git log -g` or `git reflog` ?

Comment: yeah reflog + hard reset was the thing I was searching. I am so happy now. Thought it was all lost :-) What is the difference of reflog and log?

Comment: How would be the normal way to skip version B?

Comment: for one moment I thought you were the same Charles from my solution :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605681/sorting-out-a-git-mess/638551#638551) worked in my case:

```
git reflog
git reset --hard HEAD@{ref}
```

Then I needed to pull the changes (for the final commit + push):

```
git pull origin master
```

Otherwise I got the error: failed to push some refs to xy